# How to execute a install.php on a server

Tags: php, web

i am a complete noob to websites and thought the best way to go was just jup in and see how i go at making one. I spent 4 hrs last night trying to find an answer to this question to no avail if somebody could help me out this would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Question:

i have a freehosting account i uploaded a folder with an install.php application in the read me it states

> "3) Run the install file YAS25install.php from your browser. The
>   install script will ask for your database details and allow you to
>   enter specifics for your arcade. The script will attempt to make
>   certain folders writeable. If unsucessful please chmod these folders
>   through your host's cpanel or ftp"

.

sounds easy however i have no idea how to run afore mentioned file. i can view the code if i want but thats no help and when i tried using the full path in another tab i get 404 not found.

maybe im not using the right path ?

thankyou for your time any help will realy be apreciated as im totaly lost at this point

Comment: Type in your browser something like `http://{yourdomain}/install.php`

Comment: Please provide FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) which resolves at the root of your web server, then provide the full path of the location where you've uploaded the files to. Essentially the path should look something like this: `http://yourFQDN/path/to/YAS25install.php`

Comment: it just says "oops google chrome could not connect"

Comment: If you want help, provide the details I've asked for. Without them, we can only tell you the theory, but we can't help you directly.

Comment: http://blazearcade/public_html/yas251full/YAS251install.php

also tried

http://blazearcade/yas251full/YAS251install.php

Comment: `blazearcade` is not a FQDN. It's just a hostname. Does that hostname resolve to your root directory? If so, does `blazearcade/public_html/` resolve to anything? Do you have a 'public_html' directory under your root web server directory? P.S. Just a shot in the dark - the quote in your question says `YAS25install.php` and the URIs you've provided say `YAS251install.php`

Comment: blazearcade/public_html/ resolves to oops could not connect so i assume  blazearcade is not my root directory. where can i find this ? i found a guide for home directory and i have that if its is any use ?

in cpanel i do have a public_html folder i assumed that was where all my websites stuff should be like index n such.

i found a similar question but in the answer it says 



The root directory for your primary domain is the public_html folder. 

How do i put that in to use ?

thank you for your time SimpleAnecdote

Comment: Ok, your issue here is that you are trying to access a hostname which you've not defined. For now, I would say forget defining a hostname. You just need to find the server's IP address. If you're using cPanel - it should tell you the server's IP address on the sidebar (I think, it's been 12 years since I last used cPanel). Alternatively, if you have a domain name setup for the account - that should work too (but I'm assuming you do not have a configured domain name yet). So after you know the IP address the path you should put in the browser will be `http://{ip.add.re.ss}/...`

Comment: ok that did something new so progress! thank you :D

However all it does is show a blank tab :/

Comment: i fiddled a bit and used http://ip.address..132/public_html/yas251full/YAS251install.php

and i got 

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /public_html/yas251full/YAS251install.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at ip.address.132 Port 80

Comment: You're welcome. Your new issue sounds like a permissions issue. If you've uploaded the files via FTP, browse the directory via the same FTP program and edit the permissions. To avoid further issues (but abandoning security) just put 777 permissions on the entire 'yas251full` directory and make sure you enable +x (execute permission) on 'YAS251install.php' file. This is assuming your server is Linux based. For Windows based I'm afraid my knowledge is lacking.

Comment: right now i have another issue or maybe the same one im not sure.

i use the url http://ip.address..132/public_html/ya

s251full/YAS251install.php

and i get a blank page then i view source and i get 
.........
<!--#set var="title" value="404 Not Found" -->
<!--#set var="msg" value="The server can not find the requested page:" -->
<!--#include virtual="cp_errordocument.shtml" -->........
....... 404 error again

Comment: If you using public hosting, you must enter your domain name, not ip address. You should read your hoster's instruction how to get site on default folder, or you may add domain name (yours or not) to hosting, and use it. If this domain name not yours, type `ipaddress domainname` to hosts file (in Windows). Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i worked it out i had registered my domain name with godaddy and hosted it on freehosting but i did not update  Nameservers. on godaddy so was a small over site on my part thanks for all the help guys :)

how to change nameserver on godaddy:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names?countrysite=uk